# how to create an input field html compatible?

Tags: html, forms, wysiwyg

Need some advice on WYSIWYG editor tool! As far as I understand, most of the WYSIWYG editor tools out there support only textarea field rather than the input field ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could try to create a textarea that is only one line in height, that would probably fit your needs.

Comment: thanks for suggestion. Is there an alternate way to strip all html data in the <input type="text"> field instead of textarea?